# Do you need to use useEffect for a react component to update after receiving a get response or should useState be sufficient?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been attempting to write a simple app that displays a suggested change to text that is computed in python and served through a flask back end.  The flask server sees the get request but the react app does not seem to update.  I have read about using useEffect but the tutorial I followed to write this code did not include it.  Here is my code:

```
import styles from './App.module.scss'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
    const [CurrentParagraph, setCurrentParagraph] = useState({
        previous: '',
        active: '',
        next: '',
        suggested: ''
    });
    function getData() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/CurrentParagraph")
            .then((response) => {
                const res = response.data
                setCurrentParagraph({
                    previous: res.previous,
                    active: res.active,
                    next: res.next,
                    suggested: res.suggested
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.response) {
                    console.log(error.response)
                    console.log(error.response.status)
                    console.log(error.response.headers)
                }
            })
    } 
    

    return (
        <div className={styles.App}>
            <header className={styles['App-header']}>
                <div className={styles['text-container']}>
                    <h1>Paragraph x/total</h1></div>
                <div className={styles.text_return_box}>
                    <div className={styles.originalParagraphColumn}>
                        <p className={styles.orig_para_previous}>{CurrentParagraph.previous}</p>
                        <p className={styles.orig_para}> {CurrentParagraph.active}</p>
                        <p className={styles.orig_para_next}>{CurrentParagraph.next}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.vertical_divider} />
                    <div className={styles.originalParagraphColumn}>
                        <p className={styles.orig_para_previous}>{CurrentParagraph.previous}</p>
                        <p className={styles.orig_para}> {CurrentParagraph.suggested}</p>
                        <p className={styles.orig_para_next}>{CurrentParagraph.next}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className={styles.ButtonHolder}>
                        <button className={styles.Button} onClick={getData} >Back</button>
                        <button className={styles.Button} onClick={getData} >Reject</button>
                        <button className={styles.Button} onClick={getData} >Accept</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried using useEffect but I keep getting errors in regards when I try to wrap my function with it.

Comment: We need specifics. What are "errors" you keep getting? It could be a Flask issue, or a front end issue. You need to narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

The react app is not updating because you are not hitting the actual api, You need to call the `getData()` function inside `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `async` function. getData function should be async.

```
async function getData() { //your code }

useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason is that you have defined the function getData() but have not called it. call it inside useEffect hook

firstly import the hook

```
import { useEffect } from 'react;
```

then

```
useEffect(() => {
 getData();
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, there is no useEffet(delcare but not use)
So your question is how to use effect? Or where should I put it?
common usage of useEffect is

```
useEffect(() => {
function()
},[]);
```

Comment: This answer is mainly fine but please try to use a code snippet using the code of the question in order to make it easier for the user to understand.